# Delete specific rows from a JQuery Datatable

Tags: jquery, jsp, datatables

I have three JQuery DataTables in my JSP page on different tabs where I want to display almost the same table, with a slight modification. The table on the first tab goes as:

```
<table id="firstTable">
<tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${A_List}" varStatus="status" var="alist">
        <tr role="row" id="colorRow" data-user="${alist.D}">
            <td>${alist.A}</td>
            <td>${alist.B}</td
            <td>${alist.C}</td>
            <td>${alist.D}</td>
        </tr>    
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now, the second table on the second tab:

```
 <table id="secondTable">
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${A_List}" varStatus="status" var="alist">
            <tr role="row" id="colorRow" data-user="${alist.D}">
                <td>${alist.A}</td>
                <td>${alist.B}</td
                <td>${alist.C}</td>
                <td>${alist.D}</td>
            </tr>    
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

And the third table goes as:

```
<table id="thirdTable">
<tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${A_List}" varStatus="status" var="alist">
        <tr role="row" id="colorRow" data-user="${alist.D}">
            <td>${alist.A}</td>
            <td>${alist.B}</td
            <td>${alist.C}</td>
            <td>${alist.D}</td>
        </tr>    
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now, on the first table, I want to display everything. On the second table, I want to display only the rows which have "Yes" as their value in the last column and the third table displays all the rows which have "No" as their value in the last column. Additionally, there are rows which neither have a "Yes" or a "No". They can be completely ignored. For this, I tried to implement it as:

```
  $(function(){
            var firstTable = $('#firstTable').DataTable();
var secondTable = $('#secondTable').DataTable();
var thirdTable = $('#thirdTable').DataTable();

            $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                      function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
                          return $(firstTable.row(dataIndex).node()).attr('data-user') == 'YES';
                      });
            secondTable.draw();

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                      function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
                          return $(secondTable.row(dataIndex).node()).attr('data-user') == 'NO';
                      });
            thirdTable.draw();
        });
```

However, this gives doesn't do as intended. The second tab does appear, but when I try to filter out anything using the search tab, the first and the second, both tables are messed up.
I also tried `fnDeleteRow`. Didn't work either. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like a fun problem, perhaps you could work up a JSFiddle with static values so we can have more of a play? I'd also beware of your use of the `id="colorRow"` for each row will lead to the html not being valid (`id` should be unique). There is sometimes an issue with tables on initially hidden divs though... check http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nu3hLqLk/2/ 
I've setup the Fiddle as asked. Thanks. :)

Comment: Ahh now there you go, that there JSFiddle isn't valid HTML is it? I could spend 20 minutes sorting it into valid HTML and adding the libraries (jQuery, DataTables, Bootstrap...?) but that's not really what I want to help you with. If you could get it at least working as three examples of DataTables I'll take a look at your problem...

Comment: I've added the JQuery and DataTable libraries. However, only the first table is initialized as a DataTable. I dunno what seems to be the problem. Can you please take a look. Also, I haven't used Fiddle much, in the past, so Sorry for the inconvinience. :/

Comment: Okay, you have an issue with your `ID`s still, there are two things with the `id` of firstTable, secondTable and thirdTable (both div and table... what's DataTables supposed to do?), your tables don't have a `thead` either... and the link doesn't represent your changes. Perhaps something other than JSFiddle might be better. Some static page you can throw your code up to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you've got a `thead`:

```
<div id="first">
    <table id="firstTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>One</th>
                <th>Two</th>
                <th>Three</th>
                <th>Yes/No</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr role="row" data-user="Yes">
                <td>1 One</td>
                <td>1 Two</td>
                <td>1 Three</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2 One</td>
                <td>2 Two</td>
                <td>2 Three</td>
                <td>No</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3 One</td>
                <td>3 Two</td>
                <td>3 Three</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4 One</td>
                <td>4 Two</td>
                <td>4 Three</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4 One</td>
                <td>4 Two</td>
                <td>4 Three</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5 One</td>
                <td>5 Two</td>
                <td>5 Three</td>
                <td>No</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="second">
    <table id="secondTable">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>One</th>
                <th>Two</th>
                <th>Three</th>
                <th>Yes/No</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1 One</td>
                <td>1 Two</td>
                <td>1 Three</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2 One</td>
                <td>2 Two</td>
                <td>2 Three</td>
                <td>No</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3 One</td>
                <td>3 Two</td>
                <td>3 Three</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4 One</td>
                <td>4 Two</td>
                <td>4 Three</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4 One</td>
                <td>4 Two</td>
                <td>4 Three</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5 One</td>
                <td>5 Two</td>
                <td>5 Three</td>
                <td>No</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="third">
    <table id="thirdTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>One</th>
                <th>Two</th>
                <th>Three</th>
                <th>Yes/No</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1 One</td>
                <td>1 Two</td>
                <td>1 Three</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2 One</td>
                <td>2 Two</td>
                <td>2 Three</td>
                <td>No</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3 One</td>
                <td>3 Two</td>
                <td>3 Three</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4 One</td>
                <td>4 Two</td>
                <td>4 Three</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4 One</td>
                <td>4 Two</td>
                <td>4 Three</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5 One</td>
                <td>5 Two</td>
                <td>5 Three</td>
                <td>No</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Which will stop DataTables complaining, then your DataTables can be created like this:

```
$(function() {
     var firstTable = $('#firstTable').DataTable();
     var secondTable = $('#secondTable').DataTable({
         "initComplete": function(settings) {
             var api = this.api();
             api.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
                 var data = this.data();
                 if (data && data[3] !== "Yes") {
                     api.rows(rowIdx).nodes().to$().addClass('remove');
                 }
             });
             api.rows('.remove').remove().draw();
         }
     });
     var thirdTable = $('#thirdTable').DataTable({
         "initComplete": function(settings) {
             var api = this.api();
             api.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
                 var data = this.data();
                 if (data && data[3] !== "No") {
                     api.rows(rowIdx).nodes().to$().addClass('remove');
                 }
             });
             api.rows('.remove').remove().draw();
         }
     });
 });
```

Working [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/a9gfq39w/6/). Hope that helps (there are probably better ways of doing it TBH - perhaps someone else will chip in as this is quite hackie - it always helps to have something to look at... JSFiddle is your friend).

Comment: Thanx a ton. You're awesome! :D