# How to delete one row from dataTable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to delete one row from dataTable .

```
var dataTable = $('#dynamic-table1').dataTable(
                {
                    "aaSorting": [[3, "desc"]],
                    fnDrawCallback: function () {
                        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
                    }
                });
```

`dataTable` is global variable.

I use this statment in **success method of ajax statment** for delete row.

```
dataTable.row($('[data-factornumber=' + factorId + ']').closest('tr')).remove().draw();
```

My selctor `$('[data-factornumber=' + factorId + ']').closest('tr')` is right.

After run this statment get error in console and dont delete row:

> Uncaught TypeError: dataTable.row is not a function

How to fix this?

Ajax Code:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/Reports/DeleteTicket/',
                data: { factorNo: factorId, deleteDescription: deleteDescription },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.Result == true) {
                        $('#parentProgress').remove();
                        $('#SystemMessage').text(result.message);
                        $('#ModalDelete p').addClass('hidden');
                        $('#DeleteTicket').addClass('hidden');
                        dataTable.row($('[data-factornumber=' + factorId + ']').closest('tr')).remove().draw();
                    } else {
                        $('#ModalDelete .modal-body ').html('').html('<h4 style="color: red;font-family: WYEKAN;font-size: 18px" class="text-center">' + result.message + '</h4>');
                        $('#ModalDelete p').addClass('hidden');
                        $('#DeleteTicket').addClass('hidden');
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXhr, textStates, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

Comment: what do you want to fix? What is the issue?

Comment: The  row dont delete

Comment: you need to give your code, how are you calling `dataTable.row`, is `var dataTable = $('#dynamic-table1').DataTable(` global and available when you are calling `dataTable.row` ? Further you can try `$('#dynamic-table1').DataTable().row($('[data-factornumber=' + factorId + ']').closest('tr')).remove().draw()` to confirm remove code.

Comment: ok . dataTable  is  global  variable.

Comment: Try `$('#dynamic-table1').DataTable` instead of `$('#dynamic-table1').dataTable`

Comment: Try @Nagaraju solution, your code is not correct it should be DataTable not dataTable!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete specific rows from a JQuery Datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565382/delete-specific-rows-from-a-jquery-datatable)

Comment: I test  $('#dynamic-table1').DataTable but dont work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [table.row is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617251/table-row-is-not-a-function)

Comment: you have to post your code to get help.

Comment: [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/7c0v1ra3/) for help. Try changing `Datatable` to `datatable` you will see in console that table.row is not a function